# Do hooks run in the git directory or the hooks directory?

Tags: git, bash

I'm writing a post-receive hook that looks like this:

```
    #!/bin/sh
    # this file is in root.git/hooks

    # deprecated
    # git --work-tree=~/public_html --git-dir=~/root.git checkout -f

    cd /home/username/www
    git add -A .
    git commit -m "automated commit on push"
    # cd /home/username/root.git/hooks
    # cd /home/username/root.git

    #git pull x
    #git push y
```

I change in to a git repo to `add / commit` and I need to go back to my bare repo and do a `pull / push`.

Should I ho back to the hooks directory or just the git directory.

Comment: Note that hooks are run with env var `$GIT_DIR` set, typically to `.` or `.git`, so if you chdir elsewhere you must tweak or unset `$GIT_DIR` (hence the `--git-dir=` in the commented out command).

Comment: @torek - can you speak to Jan's comment below.  He seems to think that it will run in root.git /w out the `--git-dir` option.  I'm going to test it out.

Answer (score 2):

1. You don't go back anywhere. The working directory of the hook process is forgotten when the process exits, so it is totally irrelevant if you changed it to anything.
2. If you want to run commands on a repository, you should be in the work tree if it is non-bare or in the repository if it is bare. Where you were earlier is not relevant.
3. The hooks run in that directory where you can directly issue commands on it.
4. If you need to temporarily go somewhere, I would recommend using subshell:

   ```
   (
       cd /home/username/www
       git commit -a -m "automated commit on push"
   )
   # You are back wherever you were, before you opened the parenthesis
   ```

   That leaves the script relocatable (as much as possible; it still need the path to the other repo).
5. Actually, `GIT_DIR` is also set in the hook and you will need to unset that in addition to changing directory if you want to work on a different repository:

   ```
   (
       cd /home/username/www
       unset GIT_DIR
       ...
   )
   ```

   Environment will revert after the `)` just as the current working directory does.

Comment: I will use your sub shell method, but where is it being run when not in the sub shell? root.git, root.git/hooks, or neither? ( root.git is a bare repo )

Comment: @cadegalt, `root.git`, of course. Running in `hooks` makes absolutely no sense at all.

Comment: except that that is where the file is actually located.  How does it know?  I guess git knows some how.

Comment: @cadegalt: not sure which file(s) you mean by "the file".  Git runs the hook by spawning `$GIT_DIR/hooks/post-receive` or whatever other hook it is.  @JanHudec: remember to `unset GIT_DIR` in the parenthesized sub-shell, or to set it to an absolute pathname, or whatever is required for the sub-shell.

Comment: The post-receive hook.

Comment: @cadegalt, where the executable is located and what is its working directory are two different, completely unrelated things and the two directories are almost *never* the same (on unix).